# Vue: unexpected token: ':' in image path

Tags: vue.js

I'm passing an image path to a child Vue component but get:

> unexpected token: ':' in https://path.to.image/image.jpg

I've created a [Vue sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sara-ebn5z6) that illustrates the problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="js-product-map">
  <product-map
    :logo="https://path.to.image/image.jpg"
  />
</div>
```

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    logo: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    image() {
      return this.logo;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are passing from html then try without semicolon `<product-map  logo="https://path.to.image/image.jpg />`

Comment: @fatm Yes, that was it! Thanks for pointing it out. I'd actually reduced the code I posted and the `product-map` component had other props on it. Most were preceded with `:` but one other prop had no colon. I don't understand why some required it and others not. :?

Comment: If you passing vue data or method or anything in vue side you put a semicolon. Semicolon is like inside me is vue don't treat it otherwise. If you are not putting a semicolon it will  treat it like regular html string. You could do as well `<product-map  :logo="'https://path.to.image/image.jpg'" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do exactly? Because it's not entirely clear to me.

The error you're getting is coming from this:

```html
<div class="js-product-map">
  <product-map
    :logo="https://path.to.image/image.jpg"
  />
</div>
```

It's complaining about the `:` on the logo attribute. But I question why you're doing it this way to begin with. Typically you only want a single selector in `index.html` as the root of your app. Unless you're trying to have multiple Vue instances.

The way that you have your `ProductMap` component set up in your sandbox seems like it would accomplish what you're trying to do in `index.html`.

Comment: It's all part of a much bigger project and I was trying to only add to the sandbox the bare minimum to illustrate the problem. The problem was the colon before the property, but as I've mentioned in my comment above, some properties are preceded by a colon, others not, and I don't understand why that is.

Comment: For the purposes of what I'm trying to do though, removing the colon solves the issue.

Comment: The `:` in Vue is for the [v-bind](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind) directive.